# Why has there been little recent work on GPU compiler phase optimization?

Tags: compilers, optimization, llvm

While GPU compiler phase optimization has been shown to improve performance significantly (e.g. https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-75178-8_35), there has been very little follow-up research on this topic. Does anyone have any idea why that is the case?

Comment: Would [tag:shading] work here? I feel like we need a more general tag for targeting GPUs

Comment: A while ago ARM experimented with using a genetic algorithm to select LLVM passes sequence for OpenCL on Mali GPU. It managed to be no better (and no worse) than a manually selected sequence of passes.

Comment: I would go for either "GPU" as a specific tag or [heterogenous computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterogeneous_computing) as the more general term and tag.

Comment: This question should be clarified to say whether you mean optimising for the performance of the compiler or the performance of the compiled code; I also presume that the GPU is the target architecture for the compiled code, not the architecture on which the compiler should run, but this could be spelled out. I'm sure this information is included in the paper you linked to, but questions should make sense on their own.